# Generating new file path not working

Tags: c#, string, filepath

I'm attempting to take a file `.fdf`, convert it to another format `.g` using an external command. From there, I am trying to move the source FDF to a backup folder and the g file into a temporary folder.

To do this I am using this section of code:

```
private void populateTable(string[] paths)
    {
        string fdf_g = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\Bin\\fdf_g.exe";
        string g_fdf = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\Bin\\g_fdf.exe";
        System.Collections.Generic.List < string > gFiles = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        foreach (string file in paths)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = fdf_g;
            startInfo.Arguments = file;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\BackupFDF\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
            System.IO.File.Move("FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf",".g"), System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\Temp\\" + "FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf", ".g"));
            gFiles.Add(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\Temp\\" + "FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf", ".g"));
        }
        foreach (string file in gFiles)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader gFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
            string line = "";
            while ((line = gFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                foreach (string template in templates)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(template) && !templatesInSelection.Contains(template))
                    {
                        templatesInSelection.Add(template);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        findReplaceGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        findReplaceGrid.DataSource = templatesInSelection;
    }
```

I have checked abd the conversion is working just fine. The program, however, throws an exception on the line reading:

```
System.IO.File.Move("FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf",".g"), System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "Local\\FindReplace\\Temp\\" + "FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf", ".g"));
```

With the exception:

```
Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\James.Hughes\Source\Repos\Find-and-Replace-Symbols\Find and Replace Symbols\bin\Debug\FOX_18_83_COD_002.g'.
```

The conversion utility renames files using this format `FOX_%origName%.g` hence the string manipulation of the original file path to get the new name.

What I can't understand is why it is attempting to access `C:\Users\James.Hughes\Source\Repos\Find-and-Replace-Symbols\Find and Replace Symbols\bin\Debug\FOX_18_83_COD_002.g'` when it should be looking in appdata.

I'm totally flummuxed so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would probably help you to get your folder path only once rather than replicating that code throughout. And use the appropriate special folder rather than appending Local to the path. And use Path.Combine instead rather than string concatenation. You'll avoid a lot of potential path errors this way and it will be easier to see what path you're attempting to access. Also, if you use @ before your strings, then you won't have to escape the backslashes everywhere. Makes your code more terse and readable.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks, but doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: Output your paths on the Console prior to using them too, so that you can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: I've tried doing that, the paths are generating correctly, which I why I'm so confused

Comment: What line of your code is failing with that exception? Have you included that line above? If you find the line that's causing the problem and output the path prior to execution, then you should be able to work backwards from there to find where it's being set incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you say not sure why it's not looking in appdata. `File.Move` takes the `source` as the first parameter and it's that source that seems to be missing (`"FOX_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace(".fdf",".g")`) but I don't see anywhere that tells it to look in appdata at that point for the source. For it to look into the `appdata` folder by default, you'll want to change the `WorkingDirectory` property of the `ProcessStartInfo` object.

Comment: have you try to to add "\\" after  Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData and before +"Local.... . They aren't set automaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.IO.File.Move` takes 2 arguments: `sourceFileName` and `destinationFileName`. You did not specify the path to `sourceFile`, so it looks for it in the current working directory (bin/Debug). Try specifying the path to the actual location of the file.

[File.Move documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ahh... yeah, that would be it. Thank you!